# How can the bar chart bars colors change in plotly express

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-express

I'm facing a problem using plotly.express to visualize numerical data by discrete values (Amount of transactions by product category.
The legend on the right shows the color legend, however; in the chart area, the bars are not colored.
[Screenshot of code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQjZ9.png)

I've checked the plotly.express documentation on this and nothing seems to change, though it is mentioned that bar chart colors can change depending on discrete values.

Comment: Can you submit data that reproduces this situation? I assume that this is a situation where there is too much data in the stacked bar chart.

Comment: on the x-axis, I have the the categories (Cosmetics - Clothing - electronics) and on the y-axis I have the transaction amount (float), color='Category'

Category
Clothing        159.834276
Cosmetic        106.301922
Electronics     527.119814
Market          256.446381
Restaurant       55.341631
Travel         1538.018727

Comment: I created a graph with the commented data and it was created correctly. The only difference from your screenshot is that the scale on the y-axis is M. The data you presented would not be in M.